# PHP - using PDO with a date field not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so this has been driving me nuts for the last two hours...

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM master_rets_table
            WHERE listing_entry_timestamp > "2014-04-01 00:00:00"
            ORDER BY listing_price DESC';
    }
$this->stm = $this->prepare($sql);
$this->stm->execute();
```

Running this query outside PDO in Navicat works fine ( i get 17 records), but no matter how I try to change this up, it is simply not working in PDO.  I'm using this same code for lots of PDO queries that do not use a date constraint, and they all work wonderfully.

fyi, listing_entry_timestamp is a DateTime field

EDIT - here is the whole code block

```
if ($this->city != "" ) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM master_rets_table
            WHERE city = '.$this->city.'
            ORDER BY listing_price DESC';
    }
    else if ($this->subdiv != ""){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM master_rets_table
            WHERE subdivision REGEXP '.$this->subdiv.'
            ORDER BY listing_price DESC';
    }
    else if ($this->date_from != "") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM master_rets_table WHERE (listing_entry_timestamp > '2014-04-01') ORDER BY listing_price DESC";
    }

$this->stm = $this->prepare($sql);
$this->stm->execute();

$this->rows= $this->stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$this->count = $this->stm->rowCount();
$this->rowIdx = 0;
```

it is working fine for the other two cases...it seems to have something to do with the datetime field or something.

EDIT [SOLUTION] - Well, it turns out that the live data wasn't being pushed to the development server and i was testing it in Navicat against the live data, so the query looking for yesterday's data couldn't find anything.

Comment: define "not working". do you fetch results at all?

Comment: @your not working = no results and $this is an extended PDO class i designed that works just fine for many queries that do not use a date

Comment: would you be kind and provide us the table schema?

Comment: Replace "2014-04-01 00:00:00" with a single question mark `?` (no quotation marks) then replace `$this->stm->execute();` with `$this->stm->execute(["2014-04-01 00:00:00"]);` and tell us if that works.

Comment: @menriquez why you're using PDO if no prepared statements involved?

Comment: @menriquez, your latest edit reads that the column in the database is `DATETIME`. Is this correct? If so, you will need to append ` 00:00:00` to the end of the date string so you will have a full DATETIME string like this: `2014-04-01 00:00:00`. I've had similar problems in the past and have solved them either by appending some times or by changing the column type to DATE from DATETIME. I just saw that @Axel has the same idea. Try out his answer. :)

Comment: @Matthew oh, he doesn't. datetimes got compared with dates ALL RIGHT. Why not to test your ideas beforehand? it will take you no more than minute to run a query in console and see

Comment: @Matthew  i was trying both ways and the cut-n-paste happened to catch the try with the DATE format not the original DATETIME. I've tried bindParam() no luck

Comment: Also, object structure is essentially wrong. It's impossible for the such a property like `city` to be in the same class with method `prepare()`

Comment: Would it be possible to create an 'SQLFiddle' with your real tables and data, a subset obviously, that we can use and try and duplicate your error?

Comment: a) just for debugging purposes print $sql right before calling prepare (btw: putting the payload into the query makes the prepare() superfluous and your script might be prone to sql injections). b) leave out the WHERE clause and instead query the Count() of records, then put the WHERE clause back again, then remove the Count() c) I don't see any error handling in the code snippet, have you used `->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` on the pdo connection instance?

Comment: @menriquez, alright, sorry my suggestion of DATE/DATETIME did not work out. Your code looks fine. Have you double checked that you actually have records in your database with a `listing_entry_timestamp` of greater than "2014-04-01"? That is todays' date. Maybe you don't have records for today yet.

Comment: @VolkerK Why would you leave out the WHERE clause? O_o

Comment: @Axel : There are four things that we can take for granted ...or not ;-) (actually there are more but those are the ones am trying to address with the previous suggestions) 1) The connection is ok 2) the script connects to the same server/database/table as was used in the Navicat-test 3) actually the `else if ($this->date_from != "")` branch is executed 4) ANSI_QUOTES isn't enabled (which would make the MySQL interpreting "2014-04-01 00:00:00" as an identifier instead of a string literal) | and SELECT Count() should produce _some_ result record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO has nothing to do with date fields.
It works with dates all right.

So, look for bugs in your code/data base/environment/whatever.

My bet for the different databases. One you connect with navicat contains 17 records to match and one you connect with PDO contains nones.

Second guess is some wrong code in your db class.

What is driving *me* nuts is pointless suggestions with wild guesses.

O.K.

mysql

```
mysql> create table so_again(d datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)
mysql> insert into so_again values (now());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
mysql> select * from so_again where d > '2014-04-01 00:00:00';
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2014-04-02 00:23:16 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

PHP

```
$sql = 'select * from so_again where d > "2014-04-01 00:00:00"';
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
$stm = $stm->fetchAll();
var_dump($stm);
```

ouptut

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["d"]=>
    string(19) "2014-04-02 00:23:16"
  }
}
```

## It works.

at least with raw PDO.

- there is no problem with SQL
- there is no problem with PDO
- there is no problem with date
- there is no problem with quotes (as long as we take 17 returned results for granted. however, in ANSI mode they will cause an error)

## There can be only problem with your own code/data/input

Comment: this is my code...cut and pasted right from my IDE. execute() returns no results yet that exact query works fine in phpmyadmin and navicat

Comment: Please read my answer over. I do believe you get no results. But it is not PDO to blame.

Comment: The code you posted now is quite different from one you "cut and pasted right from your IDE". How many IDEs you have running?

Comment: you ended up being right...my environment wasn't updated...thanks for your help.

Comment: Column "d", as returned by fetch, looks like a string to me, not a DateTime. So, in my opinion it doesn't work, actually. Can't call function getTimeStamp on the value, for instance.

Comment: @GiorgioBarchiesi I beg my pardon? Can you please elaborate how your question is related to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM master_rets_table WHERE listing_entry_timestamp > :date ORDER BY listing_price DESC";
$statement = $this->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam (":date", "2014-04-01 00:00:00");
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: I've **never** seen before so much people who never run a query with date

Answer (score 0):

The only two things that come to my mind are that you might have some kind of casting error in the date parameter, or a logic path error. I also noticed that you treat `$city` as if it was a string, yet you do not quote it.

Try with:

```
if ($this->city != "" ) {
    $where = 'city = ?';
    $match = $this->city;
} else if ($this->subdiv != "") {
    $where = 'subdivision REGEXP ?';
    $match = $this->subdiv;
} else if ($this->date_from != "") {
    $where = 'listing_entry_timestamp > ?';
    $match = 20140401;
} else {
    trigger_error("No search", E_USER_ERROR);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM master_rets_table WHERE {$where} ORDER BY listing_price DESC";
$this->stm = $this->prepare($sql);
$this->stm->execute(array($match));

$this->rows  = $this->stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$this->count = $this->stm->rowCount();
$this->rowIdx = 0;
```

This should both supply a 'recognizable' parameter to PDO and ensure that `$sql` is indeed populated.

## Another possibility

You say,

> `$city` is preformatted with PDO::quote()...thats an old habit of mine

If it were so, let's suppose that `$this->city` is initially empty.

Then `PDO::quote` would make it into an empty *quoted string*: i.e. a pair of quote marks with nothing inside.

Then, the comparison `$this->city != ""` would always return **true**, because `city` is not "", but "''".

And so the SQL would run a different query from what you'd expect.

Comment: fyi `$city` is preformatted with `PDO::quote()`...thats an old habit of mine

Comment: Ah, there is another possibility then.

Answer (score -1):

```
can you tell me the output when you execute this modified query:

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM master_rets_table
                WHERE (listing_entry_timestamp > :entry_date)
                ORDER BY listing_price DESC';
        }
    $this->stm = $this->prepare($sql);
    $this->stm->execute(array("entry_date"=>"2014-04-01 00:00:00"));
```

Comment: why do you need the output and why do you think it would be any different?